# gremlin python clone traversal

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlinpython

I'm using gremlin-python to connect to gremlin-server and I'm trying to build up a query incrementally but I'm getting stuck. I have an initial part of my query like the following:

```
query = g.V().hasLabel('<some_label>')
```

Now I would like to do multiple things with this query, firstly I just want a count:

```
query.count().next()
```

Now if I do anything else using the `query` variable the count step is on the traversal, so something like the following doesn't work:

```
query.out('<some_edge_label>').valueMap().toList()
```

Looking at the docs it seems like I need to clone the traversal so I replaced the above with:

```
query = g.V().hasLabel('<some_label>')

count_query = query.clone()
count_query.count().next()
```

But `query` still has the `count()` step on it, when I print the bytecode even though I cloned it. Is this the expected behaviour for gremlin-python? Here is a complete example of what I'm talking about, printing the bytecode at each step:

```
query = g.V().hasLabel('alabel')
print(query)
q_count = query.clone()
print(q_count.count())
print(query)

[['V'], ['hasLabel', 'alabel']]
[['V'], ['hasLabel', 'alabel'], ['count']]
[['V'], ['hasLabel', 'alabel'], ['count']]
```

What do I do to clone/copy the start of the traversal so I can reuse it in gremlin-python?

Comment: Which version of the Python client are you using? There were some fixes in the area of deep cloning traversals in the 3.4.7 (3.3.11) release (June 2020)

Comment: yep, that was the issue

Comment: Cool I'll make a quick answer post in case others see this and have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some fixes in the area of deep cloning traversals in the 3.4.7 (3.3.11) [1] [2] Apache TinkerPop release (June 2020). Installing one of those drivers should help.

[1] https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/CHANGELOG.asciidoc

[2] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2350

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this issue was a bug in gremlin-python and has been fixed in version 3.4.7. Updating the version solved my issue.